# socket connection always successful

Tags: c, sockets, winapi

I'm beginner in winsock programming and i witnessed a peculiar behaviour of the **connect** function to establish a socket connection.The socket function succeeds even though there's no valid host in the network .For example there's no host with the ip **192.168.4.28** in our network but the connection to the call still succeeds and i tried giving ip address that's outside our network for example **1.1.1.1** and it still succeeded . Is there a reason or there's a bug in the api.i have used the code in  the msdn site provided in this 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx .

**CODE**

```
  #ifndef UNICODE
  #define UNICODE
  #endif

  #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

  #include <winsock2.h>
  #include <ws2tcpip.h>
  #include <stdio.h>


  #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")



  int main()
  {
     WSADATA wsaData;
     int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
     if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
      wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
      return 1;
     }
     SOCKET ConnectSocket;
     ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

     if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
     wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
     WSACleanup();
     return 1;
    }
    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;

    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.4.28"); //No Host by this ip   address 

    clientService.sin_port = htons(80); //Port is 80 

    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof      (clientService));

printf("The socket connect return status : %d ",iResult); // always 0 , indicating success

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {

    wprintf(L"connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());

    iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
   }

   wprintf(L"Connected to server.\n");

   iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
   if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
      printf("\n socket Connection failed ");
      WSACleanup();
      return 1;
   }

   WSACleanup();
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You're probably not checking the result correctly. Show your code.

Comment: Without code we can't help you

Comment: The function returns 0 , and just a second i'll post the code .

Comment: The code is included @Barmar

Comment: And i'm using visual studio 2010 professional  edition

Comment: This program works properly for me, connection fails with error 10060 WSAETIMEDOUT. Are you sure your real code isn't using a datagram socket instead of stream socket?

Comment: we have only 5 systems in our network , and i tried for three different ip's namely 192.168.4.28 ,192.168.4.90 and 192.168.4.60 which are not there in our network but its still returns TRUE. I saw a similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573257/connect-and-send-on-the-socket-succeeds-even-if-wifi-not-enabled-and-server-is?rq=1

Comment: (1) after connection use `getpeername()` to validate the connected address is what you think it should be. (2) From a command line, run `arp -a` after your program and see if there are entries for the IP addresses that you believe are not present on your network.

Comment: Getpeername was successful with an return value as 0 and there's no entry for the ipaddresses after arp -a was submitted .i pinged the systems and the message was destination host unreachable .

Comment: I compile the program and always get 10060 Timeout errors. Just to be sure, could you try another (no standard) port like 12345? Could it be in your LAN there are a router/gateway redirecting every port to a DMZ server and that's why always connect.  But it's strange the 1.1.1.1 IP also connects.

Comment: for which port number you got the timeout errors @ja_mesa

Comment: the one that you use 80, but I try with any number and always get Timeout.

Comment: do u get timeout for 80 ?

Comment: Well i tried for other port numbers such as 22 secure shell  , it gives connection timeout for invalid hosts and could connect on some hosts .

Comment: any answers on the same ?

Comment: Its still the same , the connect function succeeds even if i remove the network cable (i'm connecting on port 80 this time ). This is strange and if there's an remedy for the same it would be useful.

Comment: I tried the same in another system and its working fine.The issue can be closed .